# MFRC522 RFID writing personal data

Tags: rfid, mfrc522

i'm searching for a specific answer about the writing personal data to RFID TAG (mifare 1k). But i could not find anything.
Does the chip perforfing a "read back" verification after writing a block? Or it is something that must to do myself?
If not, how can i verify if the writing method of arduino library does it?

Comment: I believe all Arduino libraries are actually distributed as source files, so you should be able to go into the code and see for yourself.  (It's one of many things I like about the Arduino concept.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no read back verification. The relevant parts of `Mifare_Write()`:

```
// Step 2: Transfer the data
result = PCD_MIFARE_Transceive(buffer, bufferSize); // Adds CRC_A and checks that the response is MF_ACK.
if (result != STATUS_OK) {
    return result;
}

return STATUS_OK;
```

The data is merely transferred to the reader's FIFO and then an ACK is expected within a timeout period; the ACK is the most confirmation you'll get from the reader that your data was successfully transferred. If you want anything extra, you'll have to read back the blocks with `Mifare_Read()` and conduct your own verification.

Of course, all this assumes you're using this library by Miguel Balboa, though I strongly doubt you'll get different results with other libraries; there's just no point in including this function in the library when the user can easily do it if they choose to.